# Implementing a custom writable stream in Node.js that stops and starts writing to its sink based on a condition

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer

Here is an overview of the data flow in my app:

Video camera data stream ----> Writable Stream -----> DataChannel ------> Web

Some details:

- I have no control over the flow of the video camera data stream.
- The DataChannel object sends the data to the web client through UDP and has its own buffer.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
...

dataChannel = peerConnection.createDataChannel('dataChannel', dataChannelOptions);

const stream = new Writable({
  highWaterMark: 16384,
  write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    try {
      console.log('buffered amount: ' + dataChannel.bufferedAmount)
      dataChannel.send(chunk);
      callback();
    } catch (e) {
      callback(e);
    }
  }
});

const command = ffmpeg('udp://192.168.10.1:11111')
    .withNoAudio()
    .inputFormat('h264')
    .fpsOutput(30)
    .outputOptions(['-g 90', '-s 960x720', '-quality realtime', '-speed 5', '-threads 8', '-row-mt 1', '-tile-columns 3', '-frame-parallel 1', '-qmin 4', '-qmax 48', '-b:v 3000k'])
    .videoCodec('libvpx-vp9')
    .outputFormat('webm')
    .output(stream)
    .on('error', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
      console.log('ffmpeg output:\n' + stdout);
      console.log('ffmpeg stderr:\n' + stderr);
    })
    .on('start', commandLine => console.log('Spawned ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine))
    .on('end', stdout => console.log('ffmpeg has finished:' + stdout));

  command.run();

...
```

I need a way to make the writable stream stop sending chunks to the DataChannel when the DataChannel's buffer is full and start sending again when there is room in the DataChannel's buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is considered best practice but this solved it for me:

```
// prevent datachannel buffer from busting
  setTimeout(function repeat() {
    dataChannel.bufferedAmount > 16000000 ? stream.cork() : stream.uncork();
    setTimeout(repeat);
  });
```